# OpenGL drawing texture wrong

Tags: java, opengl, textures, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL and trying to draw a texture, its render code is the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GLFWErrorCallback.createPrint(System.err).set();
    if (!GLFW.glfwInit()) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
    }
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_VISIBLE, GLFW.GLFW_FALSE);
    GLFW.glfwWindowHint(GLFW.GLFW_RESIZABLE, GLFW.GLFW_TRUE);
    window = GLFW.glfwCreateWindow(1280, 720, "Test", 0, 0);
    GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    GL.createCapabilities();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GL11.glOrtho(0, 1280, 0, 720, 1, -1);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 1920, 1200);
    GL11.glClearColor(1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F, 1.0F);
    int x = 0, y = 0;
    ByteBuffer imageBuffer = readFile(filename);
    IntBuffer w = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer h = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    IntBuffer comp = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
    ByteBuffer image = STBImage.stbi_load_from_memory(imageBuffer, w, h, comp, 0);  
    int textureId = GL11.glGenTextures();
    int glTarget = GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D;
    GL11.glBindTexture(glTarget, textureId);
    glTexParameteri(glTarget, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(glTarget, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL12.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(glTarget, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(glTarget, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL11.GL_NEAREST);
    int width = w.get(0);
    int height = h.get(0);
    /** Send texel data to OpenGL if texture is 2d texture */
    if (glTarget == GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D) {
        if(comp.get(0) == 3){
            GL11.glTexImage2D(glTarget, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGB, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        }
        else{
            GL11.glTexImage2D(glTarget, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL11.GL_RGBA, GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
            GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
            GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        }
    }
    while (Sgl.window.isAlive()) {
        GLFW.glfwPollEvents();
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        /* Texture display part */
        bind();
        GL11.glEnable(glTarget);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x,y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+width,y);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x+width,y+height);
        GL11.glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        GL11.glVertex2f(x,y+height);
        GL11.glEnd();
        GL11.glDisable(glTarget);
        /*End texture display part*/
        GLFW.glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the window is 1280x720 big and the image only 392x69 but it is displayed like this:

[image]

So, it's upside down, much bigger than expected and at the wrong position.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: I remove some if clauses due to size of the code.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). OpenGL is a _state machine_. What your `render` function will produce will depend on dozens of different state bits (like viewport, transformation setup, vertex shader, dimensions of the texture object).  Your question is like asking "I get `f(g(h(i(j(k(l(m(1.0)))))))) = 42`, but I'm expecting `23`, what's wrong?", without ever telling about the functions `f` to `m`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is this okay? https://pastebin.com/1UcrFwdn

Comment: Please add the code to the question itself. And the code is still lacking the texture specification parts.

Comment: Sorry about that, now it is complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Going through your issues one by one

> **1. So, it's upside down,**

OpenGL's texture coordinates (not only GLs, this is generally true for all common render APIs) is defined in a way that the origin will b at the very first pixel you specify when uploading the data. Your image is most likely defined and loaded with the convention left-to-right, top-to-bottom in mind - so the vertex where you will assign the (0,0) texcoords will show the upper right corner of your image.

Now, GL's window space is defined (by default at least) with *mathematical conventions*, origin is at *bottom* left. And you're seeting up some proejction matrix:

> GL11.glOrtho(0, 1280, 0, 720, 1, -1);

This will map `x=0` to `x_ndc=-1` and `x=1280` to `x_ndc=1`, and `y=0` to `y_ndc=-1` and `y=720` to `y_ndc=1`. (It will map the `z` coordinate just flipped relative to the range `[1,-1]` you specified,  so `z=-1` to `z_ndc=-1` and `z=1` to `z_ndc=1`, but that is irrelevant here.)

NDC are the `normalized device coordinates`, where `(-1,-1)` is the bottom left corner of your viewport, and `(1,1)` the top-right corner, respectively.

So when you now do:

> ```
>   GL11.glVertex2f(x,y); // NOTE: x and y are just 0 here
>   GL11.glTexCoord2f(1,0);
> ```

the above transformations will be applied, and the vertex with the top-left texel will end up at the bottom-left corner of your viewport.

> **2. much bigger than expected**

You set up your viewport transformation as follows:

> ```
> GL11.glViewport(0, 0, 1920, 1200);
> ```

Now, this just definesanother transformation, now from NDC to window space. Just that `x_ndc=-1` is mapped to `x_win=0` `x_ndc=1` to `x_win=1920` and for `y` respectively.

So, the input coordiante `(0,0)` is mapped to `(-1,1)` in NDC, and further to `(0,0)` in window space, which is still the bottom left corner. `(392,93)` will be mapped to `~(0.3,0.129)` in NDC, and `(588,115)` in window space - which is way bigger than your image actually is.

It should still fit inside your window, but from the screenshot, it looks like it doesn't. There may be several explanations:

- your code isn't exactly reproducing the issue, and the

  > I remove some if clauses due to size of the code.

  might or might not have anything to do with that.
- you are using some "high DPI scaling" (as microsoft calls it) or similar features of your operating system. The size of  the window you specify in GLFW is *not* in pixels, but in some system- and platform-specific unit. GLFW provides [means to query the actual *pixel sizes*](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/intro_guide.html#coordinate_systems), which you should use for your setting an appropriate viewport for the window.
- ...

> **3. and at the wrong position**

That's also a result of your mis-match of OpenGL coordinate conventions.

> **4. What am I doing wrong?**

The code you have written uses *deprecated OpenGL*. You are relying on the fixed function pipeline which has been deprecated by *a decade ago* by now. Those functions were completely **removed** from modern core profiles of OpenGL. And even before that, immediate mode rendering by `glBegin()/glEnd()` was basically superseeded by vertex arrays back *20 years ago*. If you are learning OpenGL right now, you should really try to avoid learning that old stuff, and start with a clean core profile OpenGL context.

Comment: Thank you for giving such an answer. On the whole we can say I should stop using glVertex2f and glTexCoord2f? And start using shaders?

Comment: That's of course a matter of opinion. But yes, that is my recommendation. As a bonus, it would have made some of those transformations more clear, as they do happen in a vertex shader, which then is not a black box any more.

Comment: Okay, good to know. But is the initialization part of OpenGL correct?

Comment: not sure what you're now asking about. the GL initialization is done with GL

Comment: Are vertex shaders not part of OpenGL?

Comment: Is there a source you can recommend I can learn from? Videos and tutorials I found are deprecated.

Comment: @DanielH: have a look at [open.gl](https://open.gl/) and [Learning Modern 3D Graphics Programming](https://paroj.github.io/gltut/).